# Крестики Нолики - ошибка в сравнении значений

Tags: python

Написал программу крестиков-ноликов, все работает, но когда ввожу цифру 7 пишет: Selection not available!
То есть будто бы 7 не может сравнить с 7 в функции available(location, board). Не понимаю где закралась ошибка.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output #to clear the output (specific to Jupyter notebooks and ipython)
from random import randint

def draw(board):

for row in board:
    print ("\t      {} | {} | {}".format(*row))
    print ("\t    ","-"*10)




def available(location, board):

for row in board:
    for col in row:
        if location == col:
            return False
        else:
            return True


def mark(player, location, board):
for row in board:
    if location in row:

        ind = row.index(location)
        row.pop(ind)
        row.insert(ind, player)

def check_win(board):


if board[0][0] == board[1][0] and board[1][0] == board[2][0]:
    return True
elif board[0][1] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][1]:
    return True
elif board[0][2] == board[1][2] and board[1][2] == board[2][2]:
    return True
elif board[0][0] == board[0][1] and board[0][1] == board[0][2]:
    return True
elif board[1][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[1][2]:
    return True
elif board[2][0] == board[2][1] and board[2][1] == board[2][2]:
    return True
elif board[0][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
    return True
elif board[0][2] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][0]:
    return True
else:
    return False

def check_tie(board):

    for row in board:
        for col in row:
            if col.isdigit():
                return False
                break
            else:
                return True


def dashes():

print("o" + 35 *'-' + "o")

def display(message):

print("|{:^35s}|".format(message))

def main():
# initializing game
board = [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]
# select the first player randomly
player = ['X', 'O']
turn = randint(0, 1)

win = False
tie = False
while(not win and not tie):
    # switch players
    turn = (turn + 1) % 2
    current_player = player[turn] # contains 'X' or 'O'

    clear_output()

    # display header
    dashes()
    display("TIC TAC TOE")
    dashes()

    # display game board
    print()
    draw(board)
    print()

    # display footer
    dashes()
    # player select a location to mark
    while True:
        location = input("|{:s} Turn, select a number (1, 9): ".format(current_player))
        if available(location, board):
            break # Only the user input loop, main loop does NOT break
        else:
            print("Selection not available!")
    dashes()

    # mark selected location with player symbol ('X' or 'O')
    mark(current_player, location, board)

    # check for win
    win = check_win(board)

    # check for tie
    tie = check_tie(board)


# Display game over message after a win or a tie
clear_output()

# display header
dashes()
display("TIC TAC TOE")
dashes()

# display game board (Necessary to draw the latest selection)
print()
draw(board)
print()

# display footer
dashes()
display("Game Over!")
if(tie):
    display("Tie!")
elif(win):
    display("Winner:")
    display(current_player)
dashes()



main()
```

Comment: `available(location, board)` у вас неправильно работает. При первом ходе, если я выберу 7, 4 или 1 она скажет `false`. Это на мой взгляд, неправильно

Comment: странно, у меня работает все кроме 7

Comment: Попробуйте всегда вводить любое число, отличное от 7, например 2. И увидите что программа работает неправильно. По-моему в ваших алгоритмах вообще мало правильного

Comment: У вас неправильно работают функции `available(location, board)`, `check_tie(board)`. Ну и если заполнена последняя клетка и игрок выиграл, то он ... Та дам, не выиграл

Comment: можете помочь конкретикой?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ошибки исправил. Вот решение:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output #to clear the output (specific to Jupyter notebooks and ipython)
from random import randint

def draw(board):

for row in board:
    print ("{:^3s}|{:^3s}|{:^3s}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
    if row == board[0] or row == board[1] :
        print ("-"*11)



def available(location, board):

for row in board:
if location in row:
  return True
return False


def mark(player, location, board):
for row in board:
    if location in row:

        ind = row.index(location)
        row.pop(ind)
        row.insert(ind, player)
        return (board)

def check_win(board):


if board[0][0] == board[1][0] and board[1][0] == board[2][0]:
    return True
elif board[0][1] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][1]:
    return True
elif board[0][2] == board[1][2] and board[1][2] == board[2][2]:
    return True
elif board[0][0] == board[0][1] and board[0][1] == board[0][2]:
    return True
elif board[1][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[1][2]:
    return True
elif board[2][0] == board[2][1] and board[2][1] == board[2][2]:
    return True
elif board[0][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
    return True
elif board[0][2] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][0]:
    return True
else:
    return False

def check_tie(board):

    for row in board:
        for col in row:
            if col.isdigit():
                return False

        return True


   def dashes():

print("o" + 35 *'-' + "o")

  def display(message):

print("|{:^35s}|".format(message))

def main():
# initializing game
board = [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]
# select the first player randomly
player = ['X', 'O']
turn = randint(0, 1)

win = False
tie = False
while(not win and not tie):
    # switch players
    turn = (turn + 1) % 2
    current_player = player[turn] # contains 'X' or 'O'

    clear_output()

    # display header
    dashes()
    display("TIC TAC TOE")
    dashes()

    # display game board
    print()
    draw(board)
    print()

    # display footer
    dashes()
    # player select a location to mark
    while True:
        location = input("|{:s} Turn, select a number (1, 9): ".format(current_player))
        if available(location, board):
            break # Only the user input loop, main loop does NOT break
        else:
            print("Selection not available!")
    dashes()

    # mark selected location with player symbol ('X' or 'O')
    mark(current_player, location, board)

    # check for win
    win = check_win(board)

    # check for tie
    tie = check_tie(board)


# Display game over message after a win or a tie
clear_output()

# display header
dashes()
display("TIC TAC TOE")
dashes()

# display game board (Necessary to draw the latest selection)
print()
draw(board)
print()

# display footer
dashes()
display("Game Over!")
if(win):
    display("Winner:")
    display(current_player)
elif(tie):
    display("Tie!")
dashes()



main()
```

Comment: Бесполезный ответ.  Непонятно, где были и в чем заключались ошибки.

Comment: в функции available итерация прекращалась сразу же, надо было убрать лишнюю табуляцию перед return False. Аналогично с функцией check_tie.